# values inside the details are null

Tags: c#, .net, list, c#-4.0, foreach

I see that there are elements. But its not adding to this object, I see null for Name and bytes...

```
var req = new Details()
            {

                Saver= new List<SaverDetails>()
                {
                    new SaverDetails()
                }
            };

     foreach (var t in files.ToList())
            {
                req.Saver.Add( 
                    new SaverDetails()
                    {
                        Name= Path.GetFileName(t),
                        bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(t)
            });
}
```

Comment: Show a screenshot of how you are determining this problem

Comment: Your initializing your list with an empty object.. perhaps that’s the element you’re seeing the null properties?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, how to rectify that?

Comment: @Daniel: I think you're right, I rectified it by deleting the empty object and it  worked ..thank you so much :)